# How to convert volumetric flow rate of air into kg/hr?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, airflow

I have to convert volumetric air flow rate into kg/hr. In my system I have 2 ducts, one for ambient air and one for hot air.

Comment: What are you converting from? Unit conversions are easy.

Comment: there are charts and online calculators that give the density plotted against temperature! eg, https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/air-density-specific-weight-d_600.html.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SolarMike It's not just a unit conversion, the two quantities have different dimensions.

Comment: @DanielHatton without the OP specifiying temperatures then it's all a wag...

Answer (score 2):

meters cubed per hour times kg/m<sup>3</sup> = kg/hr

Can you not find the density of air at various conditions?

Comment: The necessary ingredients for "find the density of air at various conditions" being the ideal gas law and a web search for the specific gas constant of air.

Comment: The unit symbol for hour is h (from the latin hora) not hr

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 I prefer hr (from the Latin hora)

Comment: @TigerGuy Und ich ziehe es vor Deutsch zu schreiben da Englisch eine chaotische Sprache ist.

Comment: The BIPM specifies that the unit symbol for hour is h. Not H nor Hr nor hr. See here, Table 8 https://www.bipm.org/documents/20126/41483022/SI-Brochure-9-EN.pdf/2d2b50bf-f2b4-9661-f402-5f9d66e4b507?version=1.12&t=1685993350255&download=true  We have the the BIPM for a reason and we use units that have a single definition (hopefully, let use ignore for a moment that some people are still want to use units with multiple incompatible definitions) and a clearly defined way write them so that it is very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

ρ<sub>SATP</sub> = 1.168 kg/m<sup>3</sup> (25 °C and 100 kPa)

ρ<sub>40C</sub> = 1.127 kg/m<sup>3</sup> (40 °C and 100 kPa)

If volume flow Q is 500m<sup>3</sup>/h :

$m_{SATP} = Q \cdot ρ_{SATP} = 500~\mathrm{m^3/h} \cdot 1.168 ~\mathrm{kg/m^3} = 584 ~\mathrm{kg/h} \approx 9.7 ~\mathrm{kg/min} $

$m_{40C} = Q \cdot ρ_{40C} = 500~\mathrm{m^3/h} \cdot 1.127 ~\mathrm{kg/m^3} = 563.5 ~\mathrm{kg/h} \approx 9.4 ~\mathrm{kg/min} $